# InjectionToken: Nest can't resolve dependencies

Tags: heroku, dependency-injection, nestjs

I have a `CheckModule` which accepts configuration in the `forRoot` method using a constant `CHECK_OPTIONS`:

```js
@Module({})
export class CheckModule {
  static forRoot(options?: CheckOptions): DynamicModule {
    return {
      module: CheckModule,
      providers: [
        {
          provide: CHECK_OPTIONS,
          useValue: options,
        },
        CheckService,
      ],
      exports: [CheckService],
    };
  }
}
```

My `CheckService` uses the options:

```js
@Injectable()
export class CheckService {
  ...

  constructor(@Inject(CHECK_OPTIONS) options: CheckOptions) {}

  ...
```

Whenever I debug the application, everything is working fine. But, once I build for production and serve it on Heroku I get an error.

```sh
# Production build
nx build $PROJECT_NAME --prod
```

```sh
# Serving the app
node dist/apps/worker/main.js
```

I get an error:

`ERROR [ExceptionHandler] Nest can't resolve dependencies of the CheckService (?). Please make sure that the argument CHECK_OPTIONS at index [0] is available in the CheckModule context.`

Am I missing something here? I'm kind of clueless...

Comment: Are this options a .json file? It may be not included in dist after build. If so please check your tsconfig file if it is configured to load them.

Comment: The options are optional. A user can include the module `CheckModule.forRoot({ <options here> })` like this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my `app.module` I imported the CheckModule as:

```js
imports: [
  CheckModule.forRoot(),
  ...
]
```

This method had an optional parameter for `CheckOptions`:

`forRoot(options?: CheckOptions) { ... }`

However my CheckService expects a `CHECK_OPTIONS` which is **not** optional. This is what caused the error. Correctly marking this InjectionToken as `@Optional()` resolved this issue.

So, I've changed the code from:

```js
  constructor(@Inject(CHECK_OPTIONS) options?: CheckOptions) {}
```

To:

```js
  constructor(@Optional() @Inject(CHECK_OPTIONS) options?: CheckOptions) {}
              ^^^^^^^^^^^
```

See https://docs.nestjs.com/providers#optional-providers for more information about the `@Optional()` decorator.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like your module needs to be global.
Try adding `@Global()` decorator before `@Module({})`.

Comment: I didn't know the `@Global()` decorator. The description is pretty clear, but applying it doesn't change anything. Still getting the same error.

Comment: Try changing `CHECK_OPTIONS` to string in both `@Inject()` and when providing.

Comment: Use "CHECK_OPTIONS" I mean

Comment: I've got it working. Seems like I was importing some modules, which imported imported some other unused stuff. Refactoring these incorrect dependencies magically resolved this issue. Still don't know _what exactly_ caused it, but it works...

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, fixed it by moving adding all the providers to exports of the dynamic module also. in you case add:
exports: [ {
provide: CHECK_OPTIONS,
useValue: options,
},
CheckService]